# Now showing URL image discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, embed

This is the code:

```
fetch(`https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=${tenorAPI}&q=anime+kiss&limit=1.`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => message.channel.send() + message.say(json.results[0].url))
    
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**${user.username}** you've kissed by **${message.author.username}**! OwO`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setImage(`https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=${tenorAPI}&q=anime+kiss&limit=1.gif`)
   message.channel.send(embed).then(message.react(''));
    return;
```

I want to know how can I do to see the GIF

[image: See]

Other command not embedded it shows

[image]

Comment: Does the API return an image or a JSON that contains the URL of the image?

Comment: yes it does....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly now, this is the code,it is similar to the previous user but there was an error

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**${user.username}** you've kissed by **${message.author.username}**! OwO`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
fetch(`https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=${tenorAPI}&q=anime+kiss&limit=1`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
     embed.setImage(json.results[0].media[0].gif.url);
     message.channel.send(embed).then(message.react(''));
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this problem when I created a gif search function on my bot.

The way around this is to not use the url property, but rather the `.media[0].gif.url` when using the setImage method on embeds.

Also, it's a good idea to not set your image to have your api key, lol

The following code should work:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**${user.username}** you've kissed by **${message.author.username}**! OwO`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
fetch(`https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=${tenorAPI}&q=anime+kiss&limit=1.`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
     embed.setImage(json.results[0].media[0].gif.url);
     message.channel.send(embed).then(message.react(''));
   })
```

Comment: what the linked text or... https://imgur.com/09uzft8

Comment: How can i fix it? This is the all code = https://pastebin.com/m6D1Vt9c

Comment: bro what the heck?